# Create doc with subcollection in one shot

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have collection called root

Can I create document with its subcollection in one call?

I mean if I do:

```
db.Collection("root").document("doc1").Collection("sub").document("doc11").Set(data)
```

Then will that create the structure in one shot? 
To be honest I gave this a try and doc1 had an italics heading which I thought only for deleted docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared doesn't create an actual document. It merely "reserves" the ID for a document in `root` and then creates a `sub` collection under it with an actual `doc11` document.

Seeing a document name in italics in the Firestore console indicates that there is no physical document at a location, but that there is data *under* the location. This is most typical when you've deleted a document that previously existed, but your code is another way accomplishing the same.

There is no way to create two documents in one call, although you *can* create multiple documents in a single [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) or [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) if you want.

Comment: oh I see so If I do db.collection("root").get then it will not get me doc1 because it is not actual document, correct? I thought batch write is used to do creation in any order. Because obviously I can't create sub if I don't have doc1 first ( well I can like above but same behaviour would occur, no )?

Comment: Is there any example of how to achieve that using transactions?